# How can i detect if a new row is already in the database, a data change or conflict case?

Tags: mysql

The Data for my MySQL Database is imported from excel files via LOAD DATA IN FILE every night. Then they are temorarily stored in the table projekt2.

For every row in projekt2 i want to check if there is already one row in projekt1 that matches exactly (all columns), then it should not be imported.

If one column is different, the row should be identified as correction and the old row should be altered.

If two, three, for or five columns are different it should be identified as a conflict and the system should send an email and ask what to do.

If more than five columns are different it should be identified as a new row and be added to the table.

> My Mysql-Version: 10.1.37-MariaDB-0+deb9u1

I started to check every Possibility like All are equal, then only the first is different, but all the rest is equal, then only the second etc.

But this will be a lot of queries in the end and I hope, there is a more efficient way to solve this in counting the duplicate columns.

```
UPDATE 
SELECT * FROM projekt2 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT id FROM projekt1 
    WHERE projekt1.datum = projekt2.datum 
      AND projekt1.begleitschein = projekt2.begleitschein 
      AND projekt1.menge = projekt2.menge 
      AND projekt1.abfallschluessel = projekt2.abfallschluessel 
      AND projekt1.entsorgungsnachweis = projekt2.entsorgungsnachweis 
      AND projekt1.befoerderer = projekt2.befoerderer 
      AND projekt1.erzeuger = projekt2.erzeuger 
      AND projekt1.waegennummer = projekt2.waegennummer 
      AND projekt1.waage = projekt2.waage 
      AND projekt1.kfz = projekt2.kfz 
      AND projekt1.charge = projekt2.charge 
      AND projekt1.art = projekt2.art
  ),
```

Comment: How are you importing from excel? load data infile or something else?

Comment: What is a "dataset" for you? It sounds like you mean "row".